# Missing references in PCL in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

I am trying to setup a iOS/Android cross-platform PCL project in Xamarin Studio for Mac.

However, there are no references listed under References. So I can't import

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

I get this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I am using latest Xamarin Studio (4.2.1 build 1). Mono 3.2.4.

Using PCL profile 49

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it. Needed to import a dll file manually under References.